# My .NET Core uses different version of Library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel). Is it possible to specify version number while referencing?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am referencing a library like this on one of my .cs file.

```
   using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Is it possible to specify a version number because it is showing me an error

> The type 'Application' exists in both
> 'Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=1.9.0.0,

I know it doesn't make sense adding libraries with different versions, but project is being under development by large number of developers. After pull from git everyone has to remove the existing version and add library of compatible version.

Suggestion Required, thank you.

Comment: Maybe this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: You don't need Excel Interop to read or write Excel files. You can use a library like EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML or ExcelDataReader to read or create Excel files without having to install Excel on the machine

Comment: `project is being under development by large number of developers` in that case all developers should be disciplined enough to *not* change the versions of shared projects without coordination. `Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is a custom project. The [Office Interop Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2022) are part of Visual Studio itself, and the latest version is 15, not 1.9. It seems someone bumped the custom project's version without telling others

Answer (score -1):

it seems the issue related to your package managment approach , one of the quick solution approach is to add folder for referenced Dlls in your git source control and add refrence to your project to that specific dll